# How to refactor a Flutter method signature in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, refactoring, signature

I want to adjust the method signature of a dart class using Android Studio.

For example, if I want to change from named to positional arguments for `MyClass`:

```dart
// * old_signature.dart
abstract class MyClass {
  // call using myClass.fetchName(index: 123);
  String fetchName({int index});
}

...

// * new_signature.dart
abstract class MyClass {
  // call using myClass.fetchName(123);
  String fetchName(int index);
}
```

Is it possible to use Android Studio to update all method calls to `MyClass.fetchName` with a refactored signature?